# Arduino Mega TIMER1 one second interval

Tags: arduino-mega, timers, code-review

Is this timer set correctly for Arduino Mega? It should count exactly one second. And why when I print in serial monitor (seconds_passed++) is it incremented by 2 not by 1?

Full code on Pastebin: [LINK](https://pastebin.com/Efkx07WR)

```
noInterrupts();
//set and initialize the TIMER1

TCCR1A = 0; // set entire TCCR1A register to 0
TCCR1B = 0; // set entire TCCR1B register to 0
TCCR1B |= (1 << CS12);
TIMSK1 |= (1 << TOIE1);
TCNT1 = 3036;

attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(ignition_pin), ignitionSignal, CHANGE);
interrupts();

ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect) {
  //TIMER1 overflow interrupt -- occurs every 1sec --
  instantSpeed();
  LPG_Consumption();
  LPG_injector_open_duration = 0;
  unleadedConsumption();
  unleadinj_Open_Duration = 0;
  seconds_passed++;
  vss_pulses = 0;
  TCNT1 = 3036;
}
```

Comment: I am not an expert on this, but Mega runs at 16 MHz. your prescaler is 256 so TCMT1 should be 16000000/256 for 1 second?

Comment: You asked a new question about the same topic, instead of improving your previous question. At least delete your previous question now

Answer (score 1):

Your timer configuration is ok so far. Never the less I recommend using the `TIMER1_COMPA_vect` interrupt vector instead of `TIMER1_OVF_vect` which has the advantage of better readability (in my oppinion) and `TCNT1` doesn't have to be reset in the ISR (instead, OCR1A is just initialized with 62500 once in `setup()`). Therefore, TIMER0 has to run in CTC (clear timer on compare match) mode and `WGM12` has to be set in TCCR1B.

The reason why `seconds_passed` is incremented twice is because you `Serial.print(seconds_passed++)` in `instantSpeed()`. Printing on the serial interface is damn slow and using it in an ISR is a no-go!

Comment: Thanks, do you mean something like this:                                                                                        TCCR1A = 0;            // undo the Arduino's timer configuration
    TCCR1B = 0;            // ditto
    TCNT1  = 0;            // reset timer
    OCR1A  = 62500 - 1;    // period = 62500 clock tics
    TCCR1B = _BV(WGM12)    // CTC mode, TOP = OCR1A
           | _BV(CS12);    // clock at F_CPU/256
    TIMSK1 = _BV(OCIE1A);  // interrupt on output compare A

Comment: I can't guarantee because I don't have an atmega2560 available right now, so there might be little things to fix. What is `TOP=OCR1A` supposed to do? I don't think that's neccessary. Also I think, `OCR1A=62500` is theoretically correct (there is no "tick" at 0), but probably you won't recognize any difference...

Comment: It is only comment.

Comment: Allright! I suggest you try this standalone by blinking an led, just to see. If it doesn't work, feel free to ask!

Comment: @Adam: Avoid writing code in comments: it's not very readable. Post a link instead. @SimSon: 1. Adam copy-pasted from [this answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/54547). 2. The timer counts from 0 to `OCR1A` _inclusive_. If you want a period of 62500, then `OCR1A` should be set to 62500−1=62499.

Comment: @EdgarBonet so practically resetting TCNT is one tick?