# Using an Arduino to rotate a DC motor once a minute (edited)

Tags: arduino-mega

I’m trying to write an arduino sketch that makes a dc motor turns one full rotation every 60s similar to a clock. The arduino will be connected to the gate of a typical mosfet and the dc motor will be connected to the drain of the mofset  such that the arduino controls the speed of the motor. Any suggestions on how I go about this?
I’m using an arduino mega 2560 in case that’s relevant.

Comment: What exactly do you have problems with? Timed things are mostly done via `delay()` or (better) via `millis()` (like in the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example). Have you tried these?

Comment: I having trouble balancing the speed and delay of the motor so that it turns one full rotation every 60s.

Comment: You can't rotate a dc motor with just an arduino output, as you can't control the acceleration. You need a stepper motor to have a clean 360° rotation. Or an encoder or this sensor: AS5048A to detect the exact position of your motor.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to check the datasheet: https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-2549-8-bit-avr-microcontroller-atmega640-1280-1281-2560-2561_datasheet.pdf and set an interrupt on one of the timer.

Example code of this application can be found on this stack here : [How to make 1 second delay more accurate?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/54542/how-to-make-1-second-delay-more-accurate)

Another way of doing it if you don't need to do anything between rotation would be to wait by just waiting using delay in a for loop. Be aware that this is less precise than interrupts driven wait.
https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/delay/

edit : if you want to complete one full rotation every 60s

```
int i = 0;
while(1) {
  i++;
  delay(1000);
    if( i == 60){
    doFullRotation();
    i = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, I was not clear in the question. I don’t want it to start turning every 60s, I want it to complete one full rotation every 60s.

Comment: oh wait, you mean you want it to rotate one turn over 60 sec? 1 turn per 60 sec?

Comment: In that case, you will have trouble with dc motor, since you can't precisely make them turn over a precise angle without feedback from an encoder. Id suggest getting something like a servo or a stepper motor depending on your needs